# How set a main class in pom.xml file

Tags: java, maven

I have page object model for running automated tests, and I have a java class under pages package *org.jbehave.web.webdriver.pages.test*. I would like to run only the specific test.java class using jar file built based on maven pom file. Where should I add my main class in the pom file and run only the specific class?

I tried adding it in the phase, but I get the error as "Could not find goal 'java' in plugin org.jbehave:jbehave-maven-plugin:4.0.3 among available goals map-stories-as-paths,"

Here is example of pom file:

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>jbehave-web-webdriver</groupId>
  <artifactId>jbehave-web-webdriver</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>JBehave WebDriver Stories</name>
  <description>
  </description>
  <properties>
    <jbehave.webapp.name>trader-runner</jbehave.webapp.name>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jbehave.web</groupId>
      <artifactId>jbehave-web-selenium</artifactId>
      <version>3.6-beta-2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>2.44.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
      <artifactId>jbehave-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
      <artifactId>jbehave-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.4</version>
      <classifier>resources</classifier>
      <type>zip</type>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
      <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.20</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbehave-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>run-stories</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <mainClass>com.java2s.ide.App</mainClass>
              <configuration>
              </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>unpack-view-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>unpack-view-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <viewDirectory>target/jbehave/view</viewDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.1</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
          </dependency>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin> -->
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
          <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
              <pluginExecutions>
                <pluginExecution>
                  <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jbehave-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <versionRange>[3.9.1,)</versionRange>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>unpack-view-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <action>
                    <ignore />
                  </action>
                </pluginExecution>
              </pluginExecutions>
            </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run your java program and your project is maven-based, then you can use shaded type of building your jar file. It can help you to have one fat jar which all your dependencies would be added to it. **Additionally, you can specify your main class in its underlying tags too, like: **

```
    <project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>MAIN_CLASS_ADDRESS</mainClass>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

e.g. "org.sonatype.haven.HaveCli" for a class named HaveCli.

Comment: where do i add these lines in pom.xml

Comment: that is exactly shown in the above example. You should use build->plugings->plugin->... as like as above code. Actually, you can put above sample to your pom.xml under project tag.

Comment: i added the above lines after project tag and when i do maven install, i see now error as 
Failed to execute goal org.jbehave:jbehave-maven-plugin:4.0.3:run-stories-as-embeddables (run-stories) on project jbehave-web-webdriver: Failed to run stories as embeddables. I don't understand what i am doing wrong here

Comment: you should remove other build tags from your pom file. I have edited your question body recently and found out your pom file's structure is so messy. You have added some of your dependencies like guava in your build tag. You should add all  your dependencies under *dependencies* tag. I'm sure that your problem should be solved by correcting your pom files structure. check this https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html too.

Comment: I can see that. Sorry i have taken over this project from someone else. Can you please explain me what exactly a pom file and how it is constructed.

Comment: @eddieB the link in my previous comment is an introduction to pom file. But in short, it is a file by which you can set the configurations which is needed for building your project. Those configurations consist things like: dependencies, project version, repositories by which dependencies should be handled with and .... You can find out more in the link is mentioned in my previous comment. good luck. plz don't forget to upvote the comments and answer if they are useful to you. thanks

Comment: i added the following section under plugin but it doesn't run the java class. I do get build success for maven install though.